# read character array with cin.get

Tags: c++, input, char, c-strings

I try to write a program that get max to 20 characters and index them as character array then print out the array. The program compiles but the output are random words and symbols in place of the variable. Any idea why?

```
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
const int MAX = 20;
char str[MAX];
int index = 0;

while (index < MAX -1 &&
        (str[index++]==cin.get()) != '\n');

str[index]='\0';

cout<<"What i typed is _"<<str<<endl; 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: An array of characters in C++ is usually called a `std::string`.

Comment: [Enable more compiler warnings.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/k-2fCB)

Comment: `istream` has an overloaded `get()` that reads a whole array at a time until `count-1` is read or `'\n'` is encountered. There is no need to read 1 `char` at a time manually: `cin.get(str, MAX)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition un the while statement is invalid. There is a typo

```
while (index < MAX -1 &&
        (str[index++]==cin.get()) != '\n');
                     ^^^
```

Write

```
while (index < MAX -1 &&
        (str[index++] = cin.get()) != '\n');
```

Take into account that the new line character `'\n'` can be stored in the result string.